# На выходным, в субботу(,) по-моему, возникло происшествие

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> На выходным, в субботу(,) по-моему, возникло происшествие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*На выходных, в субботу по-моему, возникло происшествие* — вводное слово *по-моему* входит в уточняющий оборот *в субботу* и не отделяется от него запятой.

*На выходных, в субботу, по-моему, возникло происшествие* — а здесь вводное слово относится не к уточняющему обороту, а к слову *возникло*.

Comment: Копировать глупости — странное занятие. Вводное видим, а в какой словесный винегрет введено?

Comment: @shampar А что не так?

Comment: Если происшествие возникло, значит и пропасть может?